# Laravel 9.3, reorganize request classes structure

Tags: laravel, class, structure

I have tried to reorganize my request classes. For example, I tried the following:

Instead of: use app\Http\Requests\UpdatePasswordRequest; (in the folder app\Requests.

I wanted: use app\Http\Requests\Account\Password\UpdatePasswordRequest: (in the folder app\Http\Requests\Account\Password\

At the: composer dump-auto I get a message like this:
The class App\Http\Requests\UpdatePasswordRequest in E:/htdocs/project/app\Http\Requests\Account\Password\UpdatePasswordRequest.php does not conform to the psr-4 autoloading standard. Skip.

Is there a workaround for this, I want to organize my request files for clarity.

Comment: Which namespace you have defined in `UpdatePasswordRequest.php`

Comment: That was the wrong namespace I used. After I have corrected this, my project works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have put .php in the namespace of the file so simple changing the namespace of the file to

```
namespace Http\Requests\Account\Password;

class UpdatePasswordRequest extends FormRequest
```

This should do it!